# In mongoDb how do you remove an object within an array that contains a specific key and value?

Tags: mongodb, pull

I'm trying to remove the field from the teacher array that contains a specific subject, such as `"ok baby"`

```
{
"_id" : "billy",
"password" : "$2a$10$MKZFNtMhts6rMbnIoqXB9.Q8NHAizQAGhX5S6g.8zeRt7TpRpuQea",
"teacher" : [
    {
        "subject" : "ok baby",
        "students" : [
            "billy"
        ]
    },
    {
        "subject" : "adsfqewr",
        "students" : [
            "billy"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
users.update(      { 'teacher.subject':title, '_id':username},
                   { $pull: { 'teacher.subject':title } },
                   { multi: true }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be like this .,,, pulling data from array is teacher  and title is equal to title ...

```
users.update( { 'teacher.subject':title, '_id':username},
               { $pull: { 'teacher':{'subject':title}} },
               { multi: true }
 );
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be doing it

Comment: oh  i put 'title' instead of subject try again